# View only leading/multiple whitespace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, whitespace, sublimetext

I would like to view whitespace characters in Sublime Text 3, except for single spaces between words.

For example, in VS Code this is enabled by the setting `"editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary"`, and looks like this:

[image]

I'm aware of the built-in ST3 setting `"draw_white_space": "all/none/selection"`, which does not accomplish what I'm looking for. I've tried the package [Highlight Whitespaces](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlight%20Whitespaces) which almost does what I want - but rather than highlighting the space, I'd like to just view the "dot" to show the "invisible" space character.